# Samsung Galaxy emitting constant beeping sound

Tags: samsung, audio, nfc

My Galaxy (A8) is emitting a constant beeping sound every few seconds. I tried the following, per various online suggestions:

1. Wiping the cache (by entering into recovery mode)
2. Closing all applications
3. Reset the device
4. Update the firmware (there was a recent FOTA)

Any suggestions as to the cause or the ways to solve?

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, the issue turned out to be that a card with an NFC chip was interacting with the NFC receiver in the phone.

While there were no open applications, this still caused a constant beep every few seconds. Removing the card, or disabling the NFC, both solved the issue.